# How exactly are 準体助詞 and 形式名詞 different? In what regard? And where does の stand?

Tags: grammar, syntax, nominalization, terminology, parts-of-speech

I have read several definitions (e.g. [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E-488640) and [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E-530025)) and explanations ([here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10225227670) for example), but I am not sure any real differences are drawn except one is 助詞, the other 名詞.

The list given for 形式名詞:

> 和語では「こと・もの・あいだ・うち・とおり・とき・せい・はず・かた・ほど・よし・ふし・ところ・ゆえ」など、漢語では「件・儀・体(てい)・方(ほう)・点・段・分」などがある。(精選版 日本国語大辞典)

The 準体助詞 list:

> 「の」（「弟からのは大きかった」）、「ぞ」（「どこぞが痛んだ」）、「から」（「三〇〇斤からの重さ」）、「ほど」（「三つほどがちょうどいい」）、「ばかり」（「一〇人ばかりがちょうどいる」）、「だけ」（「三つだけあまる」）(ibid.)

But there are cases where の can be used interchangeably with こと

> 絵を描く[こと/の]が好き

In cases like this, is の a 準体助詞? 形式名詞? If の is a 準体助詞 while こと a 形式名詞, and they essentially serve the same grammatical purpose, doesn't that create some sort of paradox?

What about の in:

> あれは彼のだよ

> 赤いのがいい

How exactly do 形式名詞 and 準体助詞 differ, given that both seem to refer to nominalizers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me use these labels in this answer:

- **A**: あれは彼**の**だよ。(の as のもの)
- **B**: 赤い**の**が欲しい。こんな**の**が欲しい。(の as もの)
- **C**: 絵を描く**の**が好きだ。(の as a nominalizer)
- **D**: 彼女は学生な**の**だ。彼は知っている**の**だ。(explanatory-の)

---

準体助詞 is not really a widely used term. According to the following links, 準体助詞 can be roughly summarized as "a word which was **originally a 助詞** but has gained the role as a (形式)名詞". Some people believe it's still a special 助詞, and some people believe it's effectively a (形式)名詞 (or a suffix) already.

- [名詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E) on Wikipedia says **C** is 準体助詞, and says it's called so because it was originally a 助詞.

  > 「彼に聞くのがいい」「あちらに着いてからが大事だ」などの「の」「から」も、機能は形式名詞に似るが、**助詞に由来するので**準体助詞（準体言助詞）と呼ばれる。
- [助詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E#%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E) on Wikipedia says **C** is categorized as 格助詞 by some.

  > 「彼に聞くのがいい」「あちらに着いてからが大事だ」というときの「の」「から」は、用言の後について体言相当の意味を表す。この機能は形式名詞（「こと」「もの」「ところ」など）と似ているので準体助詞と呼ばれる。**格助詞に含める説と、含めない説がある。**
- [準体助詞](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E/) on デジタル大辞泉 says **A**, **B** and **C** are 準体助詞. (But its definition contains ～とする, implying this is not a universally accepted concept.)

  > ほとんどが格助詞からの転用。「私のがない」「きれいなのがほしい」「行くのをやめる」の「の」
- [準体助詞](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E-530025) on 精選版日本国語大辞典 says **A** is 準体助詞, but also says many believe it's just a noun.

  > これらは、格助詞・係助詞・副助詞、あるいは接尾語としても扱われ、**形式名詞、あるいは名詞とする説が多い**。
- [の](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE/#jn-171157) and [のだ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0/#jn-171961) on デジタル大辞泉 say **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** are all 準体助詞.
- [の](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE-596099) and [のだ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-596938) on 精選版日本国語大辞典 say **A** is "格助詞(準体助詞とする説もある)", B and C are just 名詞, and D is 格助詞.
- の on 明鏡国語辞典第3版 explains **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** under 助詞, but without using the term 準体助詞 itself.
- Many Wikipedia articles acknowledge **C** and **D** are 準体助詞. See [these search results](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5:%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&limit=500&offset=0&ns0=1&search=%22%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%22).
- Several websites for JSL learners I checked treat の simply as a 形式名詞.

So all of A, B, C and D might be called (準体)助詞 depending on the writer's preference :)

I personally think の in B, C and D can be simply explained as a (形式)名詞. の in A is somewhat grammatically special, but it can be explained as a noun-forming suffix, too. Practically speaking, the etymology-based category, 準体助詞, seems not very useful to me. From the standpoint of a modern Japanese speaker, I can think of no practical merit in thiking 寝るのが好き and 寝ることが好き are syntactically different, even if this の was etymologically a genitive particle.

(By the way, I personally didn't know の-as-a-nominalizer derived from the genitive case particle の. It's semantically much closer to こと/もの now...)

Comment: One of my books treats a sentence like **A** as an omission of some item understood in the context. 私の友達の本です then becomes 私の友達のです. It treats の as a 助詞.

Comment: @Nameless Yes, that's what 精選版日本国語大辞典 says, too (修飾されるべき、下の実質名詞を省略したもの。準体助詞とする説もある).

Comment: A potentially interesting addition is that **A** has a different pitch from **B** (though it only becomes observable when proceeded by a heiban word). For example, for **A**, わたしのだ{LHHHL}, but for **B**, こんなの{LHHL} and おなじの{LHHL}, even though all of わたし, こんな, and おなじ are heiban in usual contexts (i.e., わたしだ{LHHH}、こんなひと{LHHHH}、おなじひと{LHHHH}). So **A** is like の＼, while **B** is more like ＼の.

Comment: (For this reason I think of the surface の in **A** as the genitive, with the “もの” element that should be after it being deleted and only manifesting as a drop at the end, while **B**, **C**, **D** feel to me like generally the same sort of ”もの” meaning thing at varying levels of abstraction — so basically I agree.)