# のに's connection to の and に?

Tags: particles

のに is defined as a conjunctive particle which means something like "even though" or "although"; however, I'm wondering if there's any connection this particle has to its apparent constituents (の and に)? Moreover, is the の considered to be nominalizing the clause that comes before it?

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one usage of のに.

If you are talking about the particle のに meaning "even though", "despite", yes, it is composed of 準体助詞「の」＋接続助詞「に」([デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB/)).

To answer your question whether の is a nominalizer here: It could be a nominalizer, but in my view it doesn't have to be. 準体助詞 has varied definitions and interpretations. Please see [this answer: How exactly are 準体助詞 and 形式名詞 different?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93346/30454).